# Which "if clause" is grammatically correct in these sentences

Tags: british-english

Not a native speaker, so I'm confused about which one is correct in the following example

> If I had gotten hired I would have had a good job.
>
> If I got hired I would have had a good job.

I have seen somebody uses the first and somebody uses the second. AFAIK, `would have P.P` should be paired to use with "had P.P" in the if clause. Is the second the right use? If it is, what's the difference between them?

Comment: You need the past-perfect tense, as in your first example, so the temporal locations match up.

Comment: If you search this site for "third conditional" (with quotation marks) you will find several helpful discussions about how to form conditional sentences in English.

Comment: There is much variation in the way native speakers express these thoughts.

Comment: Not sure who tagged it "british-english", but "I had gotten" is not standard British English; it's American.

Answer (score 0):

The first sentence is correct, although I would probably insert a comma:

> If I had gotten hired, I would have had a good job.

The second sentence should be:

> If I got hired, I would have a good job.

You might hear the second sentence spoken as you have it, but it would be considered "vulgar" (incorrect usage).

Comment: Thanks. Could you please take a look at this sentence: The type T1 of an explicitly defaulted special member function `F` is allowed to differ from the type T2 it **would have had** if it **were** implicitly declared. Is this an incorrect usage? Should it be: it **would have had** if it **had been** implicitly declared?

Comment: They are both correct and completely interchangeable. You can also say "if it was implicitly declared."

Comment: why are they both correct in this sentence? I cannot understand it. What's the reason that `would have had... if P.t...` is wrong in the example of this question but the usage is correct in the sentence given in the comment?

Comment: "If I had gotten/been hired..." implies that the job went to somebody else. "If I got hired..." imagines a possibility that still exists - the vacancy hasn't been filled yet - so _would have had_ is inappropriate.

Comment: @KateBunting I wonder why "would have had" is appropriate in "the type T2 it would have had if it were implicitly declared." regardless of whether it used "were implicitly declared" or "had been implicitly declared" in the if clause?

Comment: If it was implicitly declared, it would have had the type T2.
If it had been implicitly declared, it would have had the type T2.
If it were implicitly declared, it would have the type T2.

Comment: Isn't it resembling the wrong structure `if X P.T something, X would have had Y`, which is similar to the second sentence in the question? I just cannot understand the difference.